# Indy (Delphi) и распознавание актуального ResponseCode

Tags: delphi, исключения, сетевое-программирование, indy

Насколько я вижу, в Indy 10 (Delphi), если не выставлен флаг `hoNoProtocolErrorException`, запросы генерят исключение при неуспешном результате запроса (например, ошибка 404 и пр).
При этом `ResponseCode` устанавливается в нужное значение (404).
Однако, если исключение возникает по какой-то другой причине (например, таймаут), то `ResponseCode`, как я вижу, не меняется. Т.е. если при прошлом запросе было 200, то так 200 и останется.

Вопрос: можно ли каким-то образом либо сбросить `ResponseCode` в -1 перед вызовом (прямым присваиванием не получится, ибо это read only property), либо определить был ли `ResponseCode` установлен в нужное значение или нет?
Можно отлавливать `EIdHTTPProtocolException`, но есть подозрение, что это не единственное исключение, при котором устанавливается `ResponseCode`.

Резюме: нужно после отправки запроса определить актуальность значения `ResponseCode`, если возникло исключение. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Если отвечать именно на ваш вопрос то ответ: Можно, но направление полета мысли от этого верным не станет, верное направление - обрабатывать все ошибки.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, об этом никто не спорит. Тут вопрос в том, как различить внутреннюю ошибку Indy и ответ с ошибкой от сервера?

Comment: Элементарно, первое это исключения(как они там в делфи правильно называются?), второе это респонс код, в обоих случаях при наличии исключения оно будет разным, вам нужно обработать все варианты :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, `ResponseCode` может не меняться, я об этом писал выше, это одна из проблем. А исключений Indy порядка сотни, если не больше. И судя по исходникам, при ошибке на стороне сервера, может генерироваться даже исключение `EIdException`, которое является базовым классом для всех исключений. Не по тексту исключения же проверку делать.

Comment: Ночь была спать хотел :) Да, все ошибки нужно анализировать, а эксепшены тем более, и да, 
1) Вы можете получить responseHeader и проанализировать его сами(чтоб достать responseCode).
2) Вы можете создать дочерний класс и изменить его поведение в части заполнения кода.
3) В конце концов вы можете написать свой класс для работы с http :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, в общем, я думаю, есть смысл просто перейти на THTTPClient :)

Comment: А потом на голые сокеты, я именно так поступил в свое время, правда это были времена делфи7...